# Selenium test run java-tests from console

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium, console

I have java file with test's suit and I compile it. How can i run test's from command line(console). I have Ubuntu 13.04. How many tried to find and could not. HTML-test don't recommend.

Comment: I sad, I needn't html-testcase. I have java test-case

Comment: If you have your selenium test cases written in java, then all you need to do is to create the jar file, run the selenium server from command line and run the test-jar from command line.
Maybe you have to check some tutorial like [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp)

Comment: So, I read the manual, but my selenium-server can't start (i don't know why, and I download it from oficial site) Give me example, please

Comment: you start the selenium server with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar`. If that is not working, please post the error message that you get. Also, please make sure you have java installed (I guess you have) and that the path to it is set correctly in your PATH variable. Simple test for this: just type `java -version` in your console.

Comment: One more source you can have a look at. [Create a Java Selenium RC test script and executing the script](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/software-testing/create-a-java-selenium-rc-test-script-and-executing-the-script/). It is a bit outdated, but maybe it helps you solve your problem.